# .nuxt folder vs dist folder in a spa nuxt project

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

every time i build my nuxt project it creates a `.nuxt` folder and a `dist` folder in my root directory. what's the difference between them? i can run `.nuxt` by `nuxt start` command, but what's use of `dist` folder? i served it with a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en) and it worked fine. but i don't know what exactly it is. it's not a static version cause it's different from `dist` folder that `nuxt generat` command produce.it's fully interactive and when i run it by that extension i can't see any difference compare to runing `.nuxt` folder by `nuxt start` command.